# How can I prevent version control from tracking temporary files?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am using Mercurial to version my source code and am fairly new to it and still learning about it's abilities.  I added my source to a repository by adding the entire folder and all subdirectories.

The problem is that now I have temporary files which show up as 'changed'.  I realized I don't need to track these temporary files at all.  Is there some way I can tell mercurial to forget all files with a specific extension such as .~temp?

Answer (score 5):

Use an hgignore file: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html

Comment: I created my .hgignore file, but my files are already versioned.  I tried both 'remove' and 'forget' but those both just deleted the files from my local system too.  Is there any way I can stop those files from being versioned but keep them on my local system?

Comment: Create .hgignore file, make hg forget and recompile your project.

Comment: Forget doesn't delete the file, only remove does.